# Correct spelling of PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, version, spelling

How do I write PHP and a version correctly? Is it with space separated or not?

```
PHP5.3
```

or

```
PHP 5.3
```

If it is spelled with space, why do we say `PHP5` then?

Comment: Spell it however you want to spell it. It's just a name. Most people are smart enough to figure out what you mean from what you type - otherwise we'd have to be extremely *carful* of typos ;)

Comment: programming-wise or language-wise?

Comment: disagree on non constructive. Upvoting.

Comment: Surely depends on the context. Apache modules/paths etc don't have a space, but references to PHP X on php.net use a space. Take for example http://uk3.php.net/strpos. Spell in what context? Also, spell probably isn't the right verb?

Comment: @user247245 Maybe this question can be moved to an other stack app?

Comment: @user247245 There is also a "reopen" request button.

Comment: @powtac If this is about chaining the tag name maybe move it meta? And PHP5 was always "PHP 5" for all i can remember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also if I don't get your question at all there is the space 
Like:
`PHP 5.4`

Take a look at:

[PHP Site](http://php.net)

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to Zend, it's PHP 5.3 with a space - [Reference](http://www.zend.com/services/certification/php-5-certification/)